# Knockout - using options in one array to update object in a different array

Tags: knockout.js

I am currently building a small website using MVC, Knockout and bootstrap for my archery club. I am having trouble getting my head around an issue I am having with Knockout.

My model contains an array of bows a user owns, which have the properties of BowTypeID and BowTypeDescription. The real data is loaded via a JSON request, which is working just fine. I have put some dummy data in below to illustrate the shape of my model.

The model contains another small array (4 or 5 items only) for BowTypes the system will allow. I managed to data-bind the "options" of a select list to the BowTypes array just fine - the valid options are members of this array. When a user picks an option, I want that to be reflected in the instance of "Bow" being updated. So in the case illustrated below the user owns a Recurve bow, and has the option of changing that to a Compound Bow, or he could select the Recurve again. The trouble I am having is updating the "Bow" instance when the value in the select list changes.

```
var MyBowsModel = ko.observable(
{
    BowTypes: ko.observableArray([
    {
        Description: ko.observable('Compound'),
        BowTypeID: ko.observable('c0b0e507-70b7-43d5-8574-7d6a0103ba27'),
        DefaultBow: ko.observable(false)
    },
    {
        Description: ko.observable('Recurve'),
        BowTypeID: ko.observable('5b9693dc-dccd-40bc-aea8-02b9f7e0a926'),
        DefaultBow: ko.observable(true)
    }
    ]),
    Bows: ko.observableArray([
    {
        BowID: ko.observable('6bf1fd74-5300-49f3-92cd-9ab14188f046'),
        BowTypeDescription: ko.observable('Recurve'),
        BowTypeID: ko.observable('5b9693dc-dccd-40bc-aea8-02b9f7e0a926'),
        CreatedDate: ko.observable('05/01/2013 15:00'),
        Name: ko.observable('My favourite Bow')
    }]), //A couple of function stubs
    Save: function () { alert('Save'); return true; },
    Visible: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The UI is using a knockout foreach binding to list the bows using this template:

```
<script id="BowItemTemplate" type="text/template">

    <div class="clearfix" data-bind="liveEditor: Name">
        <span class="view" data-bind="event: { dblclick: Name.edit }, text: Name,"></span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <ul class="list-inline text-right">
                <li><label>Deleted? <input data-bind="checked: false" type="checkbox" /></label></li>
                <li><i data-bind="click: Name.edit" class="icon-wrench"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <textarea style="width:85%" class="edit" data-bind="value: Name, enterKey: Name.stopEditing, selectAndFocus: Name.editing, event: { blur: Name.stopEditing }"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
            <li><label>Bow Type</label></li>
            <li data-bind="liveEditor: BowTypeDescription">
                <span>
                    <span class="view" data-bind="event: { dblclick: BowTypeDescription.edit }, text: BowTypeDescription"></span>
                    <i data-bind="click: BowTypeDescription.edit" class="icon-wrench"></i>
                    <select style="width: 95%;" class="edit" data-bind="event: { blur: BowTypeDescription.stopEditing }, options: $parent.BowTypes, optionsText: 'Description', value: BowTypeID, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>    
                </span>
            </li>
            <li><label>Date Created</label></li>
            <li><span data-bind="text: CreatedDate"></span> <i class="icon-wrench"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

The "liveEditor" is a cool bit of knockout extension which allows inline editing:

```
ko.extenders.liveEditor = function (target) {
    target.editing = ko.observable(false);

    target.edit = function () {
        if (!target.editing()) {
            target.editing(true);
        }
        else {
            target.stopEditing();
        }
    };

    target.stopEditing = function () {
        target.editing(false);
    };
    return target;
};

ko.bindingHandlers.liveEditor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable.extend({ liveEditor: this });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function () {
            return { editing: observable.editing };
        });
    }
};
```

Using simple CSS styles elements are shown/hidden depending on whether an item is being edited or not.

[image: The page loads, and the users one and only bow is displayed]

Clicking on the wrench next to recurve puts it in edit mode:

[image: Edit Mode]

When the user selects Long Bow, or another option, the Bow in the Bows array should update.
It doesnt - it stays as Recurve.

Any ideas on how I can get the bow instance in the Bows array to take the value selected in the dropdown list, which gets its values from the BowsType array?

Comment: I am wondering if I could achieve this using a ko.computed - bind to the BowTypeID in the bows array, but somehow return the text description from the BowType array for display... I think the problem might be using both BowTypeDescriptions and BowTypeIDs

Comment: I have ran into similar issues in the past. I threw together a [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/2LF68/) but it may not fit the overall direction you are trying to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ko.computed is a good way to go Ian, the trick/solution is to build it by looping over your array of raw Bows and call a Bow constructor (so it has a reference to the bow, and can create the computed based on it's BowTypeID):

```
var Bow = function(rawData, bowTypes){
        var bow={};
        bow.BowID= ko.observable(rawData.BowID);
        bow.BowTypeID= ko.observable(rawData.BowTypeID);
        bow.BowType = ko.computed(function(){
                return ko.utils.arrayFirst(bowTypes(), function(bowType){
                    return bowType.BowTypeID() == bow.BowTypeID();
                });
            });
        bow.CreatedDate = ko.observable(rawData.CreatedDate);
        bow.Name = ko.observable(rawData.Name);
         return bow;
    };


    console.log(self.rawBows);    
     self.Bows = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.rawBows, function(bow){
            return new Bow(bow, self.BowTypes);
     }));
```

Then your HTML needs to change to update the BowTypeID rather than the description:

```
<li data-bind="liveEditor: BowTypeID">
            <span>
                <span class="view" data-bind="event: { dblclick:  BowTypeID.edit }, text: BowType().Description"></span>
                <i data-bind="click: BowTypeID.edit" class="icon-wrench"></i>
                <select style="width: 95%;" class="edit" data-bind="event: { blur: BowTypeID.stopEditing }, options: $parent.BowTypes, optionsText: 'Description', optionsValue: 'BowTypeID', value: BowTypeID, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>    
            </span>
        </li>
```

The ko.computed above returns the full BowType (BowTypeID, Description), so the HTML references that with BowType().Description, this allows you to reference other things on the BowType if there are any; if you really just wanted the description you can change the ko.computed defintion to:

```
bow.BowTypeDescription = ko.computed(function(){
            //find the bow type in bowTypes array
            var bowType ko.utils.arrayFirst(bowTypes(), function(bowType){
                return bowType.BowTypeID() == bow.BowTypeID();
            });
            return bowType.Description();

        });
```

Both methods can be seen on this fiddle I put together (so you'll see the description twice, but with 2 different ways of doing the computed):

http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/BKV7a/

Comment: Thank you @jiggle - I had to move a bit of the code around to take into account loading via an AJAX post request, but your ko.computeds did the trick. I have noticed something strange - it might be due to ko.computeds - I usually do ko.applyBindings(viewModel) before the ajax call, and before $(document).ready() which runs the ajax call. I had to move the applyBindings after I built and updated the whole model from my JSON data. I am wondering if ko.computeds dont notify subscribers properly. Enough of my issues, thank you very much!

Comment: Great, glad you got it working. Definitely makes sense to apply your bindings after $(document).ready(); but potentially you could applybindings before the ajax call, you might need to new up an empty observablearray first for the data eg self.bows = ko.observablearray()....though you might get binding errors for the missing computeds, in which case you could create a dummy bow; but you have it working, so that's good!